# PHP DSA Signature Conversion from DER ASN.1 to XMLDSIG P1363

Tags: php, openssl, saml, der, xml-dsig

I am writing a PHP app (acting as a SAML IdP) which is trying to do a login via a SAML Response to a server (acting as the SAML SP. I am currently stuck with the server rejecting the request (I just get a 500 Bad Request).

I have written a test app (in Java/openSAML - which I'm pretty sure the server is using), and can see that the problem is that the SAML SignatureValidator validate generates

> org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: Invalid XMLDSIG format of DSA signature

Looking at the [SAML SignatureValidator code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/opensaml/xmltooling/1.0/org/opensaml/xml/signature/SignatureValidator.java) I can see that it checks that the XMLDISG signature is exactly 40 bytes long (P1363 format?) - whereas the generated signature is 46-48 bytes long (DER ASN.1 format?).

The signature is being generated by PHP openssl_sign as below.

```
openssl_sign($canonicalized_signedinfo,
                  $signature,
                  $private_key,
                  OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1))
```

An example signature (displayed as binary to hex for clarity) is as below. This is 46 bytes, but I notice it varies (depending on the random key?) from 46 to 48 bytes.

> 302c02146e74afeddb0fafa646757d73b43bca688a12ffc5021473dc0ca572352c922b80abd0662965e7b866416d

I can successfully verify this signature using PHP openssl_verify as below.

```
openssl_verify ($canonicalized_signedinfo, 
                 $signature , 
                 $public_key,
                 OPENSSL_ALGO_DSS1))
```

But in my test app when I do a SignatureValidator validate (as below) I get the `XMLSignatureException: Invalid XMLDSIG format of DSA signature` exception.

```
  BasicCredential credential = new BasicCredential();
  credential.setPublicKey(publicKey);
  credential.setUsageType(UsageType.SIGNING);
  SignatureValidator sigValidator = new SignatureValidator(credential);
  sigValidator.validate(signature);
```

Does anyone know how to do the PHP signature conversion from the 46-48 DER ASN.1 format generated by PHP openssl_sign to the 40 byte P1363 format expected by openSAML?

Answer (score 3):

That [resource from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25590/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Digital-Signatures#xx3240277xx) has explanations about how to convert ASN.1 format into P1363 with code examples. It may be useful to write a Java validation method.

And I propose you use this C++ code to generate a DSIG compliant signature from PHP: http://xmlsig.sourceforge.net/

By the way, it sounds more complex than simply generate the signature and validate it. You may be interested in [XMLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/)